# Robot framework,Selenium,Python-key down in loop in combobox skips values

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop, automated-tests, robotframework

I need to iterate over items in combobox, which is not created as regular combobox (select element), but it is some "complicated" JS component.
I wrote a while loop in python to press key down (to get to another item), check whether there is some message on the page and if the messages is not there, the loop should end. But it does not work properly. It does not go by 1 item, but it seems to go by 3 items. (I print out the "messages True/False" so I can see that if it chooses 15th item, there are just 5 messages from the loop instead of 15)
I have no idea how to force the key to be pressed just for shorter time, to move just by one item.

The function:

```
    def find_not_used_protocol(self,entity):
    actionChain = self.get_action_chain()
    message = True
    msgs=[]
    while message:
        #actionChain.key_down(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) #I tried this but it did not behave better
        actionChain.send_keys(Keys.DOWN).perform()
        actionChain.release()
        #BuiltIn().sleep(1) #I tried this but it did not behave better
        message = self.get_library_instance()._is_text_present(
            "This protocol already has a "+entity+". Please select different protocol.")
        msgs.append(message) #this is here just for better debug
    return msgs
```

Use in robot:

```
Set Protocol for ${entity}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${PROTOCOL INPUT}    20
    Input Text   ${PROTOCOL INPUT}    0001
    click element    ${PROTOCOL ARROW DOWN}
    #set selenium speed   .5 seconds  #It does not really help
    ${msgs}=  find not used protocol  ${entity} 
    log to console  ${msgs}
```

This is the combo, it might have 400 items etc. For some of them there is a message displayed on the page and for some not. I need to stop the loop on the item without the message...

[image]

Code of get_library_instance (my function):

```
def get_library_instance(self):
    if self.library is None:
        self.library = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('ExtendedSelenium2Library')
    return self.library
```

Code of _is_text_present (from Selenium2Library):

```
def _is_text_present(self, text):
    locator = "xpath=//*[contains(., %s)]" % utils.escape_xpath_value(text);
    return self._is_element_present(locator)
```

I'll be really glad for any suggestion how to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: the loop will run 15 times in worst case only, else as soon as `message` is `false` it will come out. what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I need to check if the message appears on the page for each item in the combobox, from the first one. And end the loop when the first item WITHOUT the message is found. But currently it stops at 15th item from the combobox, but in fact, the 6th and 7th do not have the message, so the loop should end here. I have even cases with more like 400 items in the combobox and it just keeps iterating even if there are lots of items without the message.

Comment: share the code of `get_library_instance` and `_is_text_present`

Comment: Added in description

Comment: change the condition to `message=Please select different protocol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally found out why the loop did not behave as expected. The actionChain really chains the events, so it has to be defined out of the loop and just performed in the loop. Now it goes beautifully by 1 item in the combo. :)

```
def find_not_used_protocol(self,entity):
    actionChain = self.get_action_chain()
    actionChain.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
    actionChain.release()
    message = True
    while message:
        actionChain.perform()
        message = self.is_text_present(
            "This protocol already has a "+entity+". Please select different protocol.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the condition

```
message = self.get_library_instance()._is_text_present(
            "This protocol already has a "+entity+". Please select different protocol.")
```

to

```
message = is_element_visible("//*contains(text(),'Please select different protocol')"]
```

and then creating a method to see if element is visible or not

```
def is_element_visible(self, identifier):
    try:
        self.get_library_instance().wait_until_element_is_visible(identifier, 10)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False
```

should resolve the issue.

Comment: does it takes some time for text to appear, try putting some sleep before this condition.

Comment: yeah I enabled the BuiltIn().sleep(2) in the function and also enabled "set selenium speed   .5 seconds" in the robot function, so it is really slow now, I can see it, so it should have enough time to check the text...but still, works as before :(

Comment: are you able to find element in firefox (use firebug and firepath) using following xpath: `//*[contains(., 'Please select different protocol.')]`

Comment: well, if I paste exactly that it finds 15 results... if I use `//*[contains(text(),'Please select different protocol.')]` then it returns just 1 which is probably what we need, but it is not how the _is_text
_present is implemented...so maybe I could create similar function which uses the `contains(text())`

Comment: is it in different frame ?

Comment: no, the element is just hidden by css, thats why it is still in DOM and loop continues...on the other hand it is weird why the loop ends in some cases...so we will change it not to be hidden by css, but to be removed from DOM completely...and then I will see..if it does not help, then I have no idea what to do :D many thanks for helping me investigate this! :)

Comment: but anyway, it still does not solve why the loop checks for the message just 5 times when already iterated over 15 items :/